# How can I receive files on ubuntu via dukto app from my Android device

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I have Ubuntu 14.04 on my PC, and I installed DUKTO app on both it and my Android device. I can receive files from my PC, but I can't receive files going to my PC.

I entered my PC's IP to the app on my Android, but it just sends for a long time after giving an error about sending the files.

Why is this happening? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling the firewall, if there's one in your PC. I faced a similar problem: files could be transferred from my Symbian Nokia N8 to my Windows 7 PC, but not vice versa. I temporarily disabled the firewall in my PC, and the transfer worked just fine after that.

Comment: thank that help me i change permission in firewall and it works